# Lag in UICollectionView on Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using `UICollectionView` for showing some images stored in `NSMutableArray`

Here is my code for cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row<self.bookMarksArray.count) {
        cell.bookmarkImage.image = [self.bookMarksimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.bookmarkTitle.text =[self.bookMarkNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }else
    {
        UIImage *bookMarkImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyCell.png"];
        cell.bookmarkImage.image = bookMarkImage;
        cell.bookmarkTitle.text =@"";

    }

    cell.removeBtn.enabled = NO;
    cell.delegate = self;
    return cell;
}
```

I have maximum 32 items in array self.bookMarksImages,When i'm scrolling my collection view, i can notice that there is a lag on scroll (for only first time).

**But when i replaced line** `cell.bookmarkImage.image = [self.bookMarksimages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

**with a static image** `cell.bookmarkImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"emptyCell.png"];`

i can see there is no lag on scroll and my collection view is scrolling smoothly .

here is my code for bookmarkImage initialisation.

```
-(void)getAllBookmarkImages
{
    self.bookMarksimages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.bookMarkNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *bookMarksArray = [BookMarks getBookMarks];
    for (int i=0; i<self.bookMarksArray.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *bookmarkInfo = [bookMarksArray objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImage *bookMarkImage=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[BookMarks documentsPathForFileName:[bookmarkInfo objectForKey:@"IMAGE"]]];

        [self.bookMarksimages addObject:bookMarkImage];
        [self.bookMarkNames addObject:[bookmarkInfo objectForKey:@"TITLE"]];
    }
}
```

Why array `self.bookMarksimages` is causing lag?

Comment: Can you add the code where you create you `bookMarksimages` array?

Comment: @joern please check my code i have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors which is causing this issue

1.Image size

2.Image Location

A Workaround is load the image in async thread with help of image path.make a array of image path,instead image

```
- (void) loadImageFromPath:(NSString*)path{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.bookmarkImage.imagee=theImage;
  });
     });
 }
```

**Usage**

```
[cell loadImageFromFile:[self.bookMarksimages objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Comment: Using your solution i'm facing Lag on every single scroll,Earlier it was  only on first time's scroll.

Comment: what did u save in array?

Comment: I saved image path in array and used your solution,Added method loadImagesForPath in my custom cell and replaced your line cell.bookmarkImage.imagee=theImage; with Self.bookmarkImage.image=theImage;

Comment: der must be something missing it not possible

Comment: @walinaqvi It's more possible that the size of your images is too big to fit in a UICollectionView to scroll smoothly. Better shrink it down to smaller than 50kb each pic.

Comment: @James i have used this code                 CGFloat scaleSize = 0.2f;

                UIImage *smallImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                                                          scale:scaleSize
                                                    orientation:image.imageOrientation];

for reducing size while storing it to document directory